# How to add content inbetween node fields on node creation?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a node called survey. Inbetween fields I want arbitrary text. The text is not associated with a field. I tried adding a "group", but could not find a way to add html. Then I looked at adding some kind of plain text field, but also no luck.

I'm sure I've done this using groups in the past, but I just can't seem to find out where to do it. Any ideas?

And just to be clear:
 - I have a node called survey
 - It has fields on it like "name" and "email" address
 - Inbetween name and email, I want, for example, to show an image and some text. I want to be able to enter the html to do this, but not sure how to add it?

In code, I would just add a type "#markup", but how do you do this via the interface?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this inbetween content is static or else you would have it as a field as well. So, I think you should just edit the template file of this node and add the fields and whatever other info you want between them directly on the file.

It would look sth like:

```
<?php print render($content['field_firstfield']);?> // first custom field
<div>
whatever you want inbetween
</div>
<?php print render($content['field_firstfield']); ?> // second custom field
<?php print render($content['body']);?> // all the rest content
```

Answer (score 0):

[Field help helper](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_help_helper)

> The Field help helper module adds a link to entity configurable fields so that users with the appropriate permissions may easily edit the help text and label for a field in context of where the field displays.

[Better field descriptions](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_field_descriptions)

> Better field descriptions makes it possible to
>   add themeable descriptions to fields in 
>   forms.

[Field Help](https://www.drupal.org/project/fieldhelp)

> This module is a container for functions that extend Drupal's core Field API. It could be installed as a library and it would work just as well.

I hope the above modules will give you what you are asking for.

**Another Workaround:**
If i understand your question, you may use a long text field (same as the body field), make it read-only (disable it), change its settings to **full html**, and put inside whatever html code (image, text...) you like.

Note: if you have the **ckeditor** (wysiwyg editor bar) installed, it will be a better way for you to just *you know lets say decorate* your text.

Answer (score 0):

[Markup](https://www.drupal.org/project/markup) is undeniably the module for the job.